# How to enable video sond in revolution slider.?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am facing an issue of no sound in revolution slider wordpress any one please guide me how to enable a background vimeo video sound in revolution slider.
my website url http://www.theautomotivecompany.co.uk/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to un-mute your background videos, please update your embed code to include the muted=0embed parameter. For example:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871<b>?background=1?muted=0</b>" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Found the article here: https://support.shufflehound.com/forums/topic/vimeo-video-sound-on-slider-revolution/